# Multi Colum blog layout in Joomla version 3.2.2

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla blog layout set with (1) Leading article (9) intro articles and (2) columns.

The problem I am having is that on the 2nd row of intro articles only (1) intro article appears in the 2nd row. 1st row and subsequent rows are fine.

I have deleted and replaced the article and images. I also added and reordered the articles but the same results.

I do see that in the div tag it is showing class="item column-2 span6" which I believe should be column-1 of the 2 column display.

You can see the layout here :http://propertytampabay.com/index.php/blog

Any suggestions on what avenue to take would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's up (that template has an override so it's hard to know) but the first row has columns 0,1,2 which is why the third one is wrapping around. The other rows only have 1,2.

Comment: I have cleared out everything in the override and I get the same results.

Comment: If you don't use the override what happens? Can you paste the code from the override?

Comment: If I don't use the override I get the same results, but switching templates to Joomla defaut template fixed the problem. So the problem is related directly to the template "meetGavern"